# Apple indoor maps for malls and airports

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, maps, mapkit

Apple released indoor maps for some airports and malls and they are available in the standard map app, but not in MapKit. When I create app using MapKit I see usual map and not the new one.

Am I missing something or this feature is not available for developers yet?

Thanks!